# JQuery <button> with onclick() as well as onserverclick(). Not possible?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a form with my own JQuery validation.
When a JQuery `<button id=btnRegister type=submit>` is clicked, my validation code is invoked and if invalid, form does not submit. All works great.

I have another `<button id=btnSave>` on this form.
I would like btnSave to fire asp.net server side event (onserverclick) only if form data is valid.

I have tried following -
`<button type=submit onclick='if($(this).closest('form').submit()==false) return;' onserverclick='btnSave_click' runat =server>Save</button>`

When I click on the btnSave, it does invoke my form's submit event handler, which correctly returns false, if invalid. So far so good. After this point, I would like the onserverclick event *not* trigger. However, the onserverclick does trigger and the page posts back, even when the form is invalid.

As I see it,  can not have onclick and onserverclick at the same time.
What should I do to make them co-exist harmoniously?
If I change `<button>` to `<input type=submit>` it all works out. But I like `<button>`'s look and feel more.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the postback, make sure your JS function is returning false.  I see your testing for false in the code above, but not returning false.

```
<button type=submit onclick='if($(this).closest('form').submit()==false) return false;' onserverclick='btnSave_click' runat =server>Save</button>
```

Comment: True, returning false does not postback but I do not want onclick to always return false. If inputs are valid, then it should return true. I tried to return the value of submit() function, but it returns an [object object]. So I should rephrase my question as - How do I get the return value of my submit() function

Comment: alert( $(this).closest('form').submit()) returns [object] and not true/false. How do I get the return val from the form's submit function?

Comment: Event handlers always return `Boolean` values, indicating whether or not the event default should occur. If you do not want the default `submit` behavior to occur, i.e. a postback, you should return `false`, regardless of whether the inputs are valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Domenic, thx, but the point is beyond that. How do I, in my 's onclick code, get the return value (true or false) of the form's submit handler? `var sts=myFunc(){return true/false;}` will set sts to true/false. but `var sts = $(this).closest('form').submit()` sets sts to [object] instead of true/false. Thus I do not know if the form's submit handler will return true/false in the onclick of the button. I must be on a wrong track, as this seems like the very basic use of button and onclick.

I found a workaround. Instead of doing -

`<button onclick='if($(this).closest('form').submit()==false) return false;'>`
 I now do -
`<button onclick='if($.fn.validate()==false) return false;'`

`$(this).closest('form').submit()` submits the form and based on user's inputs that submission returns true or false. However I still do not have access to that return value in the onclick code. So the problem remains. To work around it, I am now calling my validate() function, instead of form's submit handler in onclick. My validate() function returns true/false as a normal function. If false, my onclick returns, else continues to the __doPostback() function from asp.net.

Workaround also has an added advantage - in case the form is valid, my prior attempt would submit the form twice, once thr my own call to .submit() and then via the __dopostback from asp.net. So in retrospect, I was being way too naive. Lesson learned.